# How to type " ·; " in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How do I type this `·;` in LaTeX?

Comment: Maybe try `$\cdot$;`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sxe ! Could you provide more informations on that symbol? What is it for, what its name, what is its utf8 code (look at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm)? Is it just a comma followed by a semi-colon?

Comment: @Clément it's U+00b7 MIDDLE DOT U+003b SEMICOLON

Comment: you have tagged this biblatex, do you need this in a bibliography rather than in math?

Comment: thanks all, the methods you guys suggest are all working. sorry for the wrong tag "biblatex" . I have changed it to latex

Comment: Note that TeX and LaTeX are somewhat 'implied' here on TeX.SX :) LaTeX3 is a distinct topic -- one that doesn't apply here...yet :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol in the question consists of U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT and the semicolon.
This can be set in different ways in LaTeX, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\dotsemicolonA}{%
  $\cdot$;%
}
\newcommand*{\dotsemicolonB}{%
  \raisebox{\heightof{;}/2}{.};%
}

\begin{document}
  \dotsemicolonA\ or \dotsemicolonB
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

May be the “unicode way”:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\ifmmode\cdot\else\textperiodcentered\fi}
\begin{document}
  I'm new to \LaTeX, and I have no idea how to type this ·; in \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the unicode point in `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` you can use instead

```
\usepackage{newunicodecharacter}
\newunicodechar{·}{\ifmmode\cdot\else\textperiodcentered\fi}
```

Comment: For completion (and directed toward OP), there are also engines that support Unicode directly: XeTeX is very stable and LuaTeX is completely usable.